# Why is the Windows 10 installation process not showing all physical drives?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

**Background**

I am currently running Windows 10 Pro, which is an in-place upgrade of a former Windows 8.1 Pro installation. Now I have downloaded the Win10.iso file by using Microsofts Media Creation tool, fired ab rufus and created a bootable USB stick, to perform a clean installation.

This is what my partitions look like. Drive 0 only holds the operating system

[image]

**Question**

The installer only recognizes one physical drive, which is my Samsung SSD plugged into SATA port 0. Besides that drive, I have four other drives, three of them are configured as an RAID0 array and the other one is acting as a backup drive.

Although the only drive showing up is the drive I would like to install to, why is setup not showing up the other drives?

Comment: If they are not showing up I presume its because you are not supplying the RAID driver.

Comment: Windows (and actually any OS) can only show drives on controllers which it has drivers for. A lot of these are build in, but if you have anything to new or to old then you will need to add these drivers during installation.

Comment: If that would be the case, then at least my backup drive 1 should show up.

Comment: Not if it is on a RAID controller or a controller which can be configure as RAID rather than normal AHCI SATA.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, of course you were right. If anyone writes an answer I am going to accept it.